# Dynamic Buttons and OnClickListener

Tags: android, class, onclick, onclicklistener

Say I have buttons that are created dynamically:

```
for(int j = 0; j < spirits.length;

     j++){
                         Button imgBtn = new Button(v.getContext());
                         imgBtn.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                         imgBtn.setMinimumWidth(100);
                         imgBtn.setMinimumHeight(100);
                         imgBtn.setId(j+1);
                         imgBtn.setTag(spirits[j]);
                         imgBtn.setText(spirits[j]);
                         imgBtn.setOnClickListener(new SpiritsClickListener());
                         cabinet_layout.addView(imgBtn);
                     }
```

I want to change the text of the button every time it's pressed (On - Off)
How can I reference the buttons within the OnClickListener class?

Comment: Seems you might need a toggle button based on your question. Right?

Comment: This is kind of a test code now. Eventually they will be image buttons and I want to be able to change images

Comment: You can make use of a flag for each button by initializing it to false. When the user clicks it, set that flag to reverse( true or false) based on the previous flag's state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your onClickListener, you have a function called `onClick(View v){}` where `v` is the View that was clicked. You may use `v` to get details about the button, including its ID. You can also take this view, and if you know it is a button, cast it to a button.

```
Button clicked = (Button)v;
```

You can then use it in your javacode just as you would normally use a button.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just call `new OnClickListener()` inside that loop like this

```
for(int j = 0; j < spirits.length;j++){
    Button imgBtn = new Button(v.getContext());
    imgBtn.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    imgBtn.setMinimumWidth(100);
    imgBtn.setMinimumHeight(100);
    imgBtn.setId(j+1);
    imgBtn.setTag(spirits[j]);
    imgBtn.setText(spirits[j]);
    imgBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do what you need to do here
        }
    });
    cabinet_layout.addView(imgBtn);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an `OnClickListener` for dynamically created buttons as:

```
 // Create Listener  for Button
    private OnClickListener SpiritsClickListener = new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Button btn = (Button) view;
           String btnText = btn.getText();

            if(btnText.equalsIgnoreCase("On")){
                 btn.setText("Off");
             }else{
                 btn.setText("On");
            }
        }
    };
```

add this Listener to dynamically created buttons as:

```
imgBtn.setOnClickListener(SpiritsClickListener);
```